# open expand/ close back to original sizes a series of boxes with img fade

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry, jquery-isotope

I have a series of clickable boxes. I need to be able to expand the boxes and hide its img. I also need to be able to close previous opened one taking it back to its original height and defined width while fading back in its img. `.info` loads ajax content

```
<div class="box">
   <img src="#" />
   <div class="info"></div>
</div>
<div class="box">
   <img src="#" />
   <div class="info">Ajax load content</div>
</div>
<div class="box">
   <img src="#" />
   <div class="info">Ajax loads content</div>
</div>
```

The css, i don't know the height.

```
.box {
  width: 230px;
  height: auto;
}

.info {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}
```

I tried

```
$(".box").each(function(){
    var box = $(this);
    box.data('height', $(this).height());
    box.click(function(){
       box.addClass("opened");
       if(box.hasClass("opened"){
           $("img", this).fadeOut("slow", function(){
               box.css("width", "600");
               box.css("height", "500");
               box.removeClass("opened");
           });
       } else { 
           $("img", this).fadeIn("slow");
           box.width(230);
           box.height(box.data('height'));
    });
});
```

Comment: Your script is full of syntax errors.

Comment: cheers for the down vote. actually spent time writing an example but ye. lovely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my final code which works:

```
$(function(){
//run the function for all boxes
$(".box").each(function () {
    var item = $(this);
    var thumb = $("a", item);
    var infoBox = $(".info", item);
    thumb.click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".box").removeClass("opened");
        $(".info").empty();
            $(".box a").fadeIn("slow");
        $(".info").css({
                    "width": "auto",
                    "height": "auto"
                });
        $(".box a").css("width", "230"); 
        $(".box a").css("height", "auto");          
        $(".box").css("width", "230"); 
        $(".box").css("height", "auto");
        item.addClass("opened"); 

        if (item.hasClass("opened")) {
            var url = this.href;
            thumb.fadeOut("slow");
                infoBox.css({
                        "visibility": "visible",
                    "height": "auto"
                });
                infoBox.load(url, function () {
                    var newHeight = infoBox.outerHeight(true);
                    $(".readMore", item).click(function (e) {
                        var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter-all');
                                $('#container').isotope({
                                    filter: selector
                                });
                                $('#container').isotope('reloadItems');
                                return false;
                    });
                    $('<a href="#" class="closeBox">Close</a>"').appendTo(infoBox).click(function (e) {
                                e.preventDefault();
                                $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: 0}, 500);
                                $('#container').isotope('reLayout');
                            });
                    item.animate({
                        "width": "692",
                        "height": newHeight
                    }, 300);
                    thumb.animate({
                                "width": "692",
                                "height": newHeight
                    }, 300);
                    infoBox.animate({width: 692, height: newHeight}, function () {
                                $('#container').isotope('reLayout', function () {
                                    Shadowbox.setup();
                                    item.removeClass("loading");
                                    infoBox.css({
                                            "visibility": "visible"
                                    });
                                        var videoSpan = infoBox.find("span.video");
                            iframe = $('<iframe/>', {
                                            'frameborder': 0,
                                            'class': 'tide',
                                            'width': '692',
                                            'height': '389',
                                            'src': 'http://player.vimeo.com/video/' + videoSpan.data("vimeoid") + '?autoplay=0&api=1'
                            });
                            videoSpan.replaceWith(iframe);

                                });
                    });
            });
            };
        });
});
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

There were a few syntax errors, like @Diodeus has mentioned. You should always use a debugger first to find out.

You also had `if(box.hasClass(".opened"))` which is wrong (you shouldn't add a dot before the class there). You also had `box.addClass('opened');` just before that `if`, which  breaks the functionality (you should add/remove the class when you show/hide the content, nowhere else).

Is this what you were looking for?

```
    $(".box").each(function(){
        var box = $(this);
        box.data('height', $(this).height());
        box.click(function(){
           if(!box.hasClass("opened")){
               $("img", box).fadeOut("slow", function(){
                   box.css("width", "600");
                   box.css("height", "500");
                   box.removeClass("opened");
               });
           } else { 
               $("img", box).fadeIn("slow");
               box.width(230);
               box.height(box.data('height'));
                box.addClass("opened");
            }                
        });
    });​
```

Comment: you're welcome. I think I screwed up the add/removeClass. It should be the other way around `if (!hasclass) show,addclass else hide,removeclass`

Comment: it opens one box, fades out, fine. but it doesn't close the previous if you open another

Comment: Then trigger `$(".box.opened").click();` inside the `if` clause (in my latest example).

Comment: how could you click if you haven't added a class yet?

Comment: you click any class that's currently open. Any time you click an unopened div you want to click on all the open divs in order to close them (there will be max. 1, because you run it every time before openeing a div)

Comment: i'm still struggling to be honest, it is not supposed to be that difficult but i'm banging my head over it instead, this is a pastebin with the actual code i'm using, tried so many solutions, yours included with no luck: http://pastebin.com/qNthGncK

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/uFz5A/

```
$(".box").each(function(){
    var box = $(this);
    box.data('height', $(this).height());
    box.click(function(){

       if(box.hasClass("opened")){
           $("img", box).fadeOut("slow", function(){
               box.css({"width":"600","height":"500"});
               box.removeClass("opened");
           });
       } else { 
           $("img", box).fadeIn("slow");
           box.width(230);
           box.height(box.data('height'));
           box.addClass("opened");
      };

  });
});
```

​

Comment: It would work because of the animation, but the `box.addClass("opened")` really belongs inside the if clause.