# open a box and close back the other to its original sizes

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [open expand/ close back to original sizes a series of boxes with img fade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9331498/open-expand-close-back-to-original-sizes-a-series-of-boxes-with-img-fade)

I'm struggling with this logic and i can't get it to work. I need to run through each box in order to get the original height and save it. Then i need to be able to click and expand and item while checking if any other is open and if it is, close it back to its original height and width (it's a set width). The only bit which i'm struggling with is this what I have at the start of the full script, I have commented it with my (i believe wrong) logic of what i'm trying to do. The code that follows this part is fine, if you want to double check it here it is a pastebin with the full script: http://pastebin.com/u72Q5Cqj

Basic html structre

```
<div class="box">
  <img src="test.jpg" />
  <div class="info"></div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <img src="test2.jpg" />
  <div class="info"></div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <img src="test3.jpg" />
  <div class="info"></div>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
    //run the function for all boxes
    $(".box").each(function () {
            var item = $(this);
            var thumb = $("a", item);
            var infoBox = $(".info", item);
            // save each box original height 
            $.data(this, 'height', $(this).height());
            item.click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    // remove any box with class "opened"
                    $(".box").removeClass("opened");
                    // this is to empty ".info" which is a child div in which
                    // I load  content via ajax into
                    $(".info").empty();
                    // here i'm saying if any box doesn't have a class "opened"
                    // fadeIn its `<a>`, i am fadingOut later in the code
                    $(".box a").not(".opened").fadeIn("slow");
                    //set back `.info`width and height to auto, is empty anyway
                    $(".box .info").not.css({
                            "width": "auto",
                            "height": "auto"
                    });
                    // in here i'm trying to set back any box without a class "opened"
                    // back to its original width which is a set width
                    $(".box").not(".opened").css("width", "230");
                    // in here i'm trying to set back any box without a class "opened"
                    // back to its original height saved at the beginning of the code 
                    $.data($(".box"), 'height');
                    // now I add the class opened to this clicked item
                    item.addClass("opened");      
                    // check if it has a class "opened" and if so do the rest 
                    if (item.hasClass("opened")) {
                            var url = this.href;.................etc
```

Comment: I can't quite picture your idea. Can you post a jsFiddle or image explaining what it's supposed to do? I don't get why use `each()` either... You could also use `slideUp()/slideDown()`

Comment: What am I supposed to look for there?

Comment: in the live link? we have a series of boxes, if i click on one it should fade out its img, expand and load content in. If any other is open, close it, empty the div from the loaded content, fade the image back it and set back its original sizes. Everything works but i can't get the open and back to original szes to work: In this paste bin the whole code: http://pastebin.com/u72Q5Cqj

Comment: I keep clicking the boxes but nothing happens.

Comment: ye..that's because of the issue :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I've no way to try a solution but your code has a few errors.
You're declaring `newHeight` twice, `iframe` is not declared and you have an unexpected `;` at the end of your `if` statement.
Then, why are you calling the `click()` event on `$(this)` inside `each()`? It seems unnecessary and it's probably no good for performance. You can declare your variables outside of the loop and the chain the click event.

```
$('.box').each().click();
```

And finally, I suggest you create a function for your `load()` and `click()` events to keep things DRY.

Comment: I need to run .each for the boxes to save their height. CLeaned the repeatition of the 'newHeight' and th ifram is declared like thi 'iframe = $('<iframe/...' the site now works, but i just can't get the closed item back to its original height, apart from that is fine: http://www.robertomarras.com/wptest/

Answer (score 0):

this is my final code which works:

```
$(function(){
//run the function for all boxes
$(".box").each(function () {
    var item = $(this);
    var thumb = $("a", item);
    var infoBox = $(".info", item);
    thumb.click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".box").removeClass("opened");
        $(".info").empty();
            $(".box a").fadeIn("slow");
        $(".info").css({
                    "width": "auto",
                    "height": "auto"
                });
        $(".box a").css("width", "230"); 
        $(".box a").css("height", "auto");          
        $(".box").css("width", "230"); 
        $(".box").css("height", "auto");
        item.addClass("opened"); 

        if (item.hasClass("opened")) {
            var url = this.href;
            thumb.fadeOut("slow");
                infoBox.css({
                        "visibility": "visible",
                    "height": "auto"
                });
                infoBox.load(url, function () {
                    var newHeight = infoBox.outerHeight(true);
                    $(".readMore", item).click(function (e) {
                        var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter-all');
                                $('#container').isotope({
                                    filter: selector
                                });
                                $('#container').isotope('reloadItems');
                                return false;
                    });
                    $('<a href="#" class="closeBox">Close</a>"').appendTo(infoBox).click(function (e) {
                                e.preventDefault();
                                $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: 0}, 500);
                                $('#container').isotope('reLayout');
                            });
                    item.animate({
                        "width": "692",
                        "height": newHeight
                    }, 300);
                    thumb.animate({
                                "width": "692",
                                "height": newHeight
                    }, 300);
                    infoBox.animate({width: 692, height: newHeight}, function () {
                                $('#container').isotope('reLayout', function () {
                                    Shadowbox.setup();
                                    item.removeClass("loading");
                                    infoBox.css({
                                            "visibility": "visible"
                                    });
                                        var videoSpan = infoBox.find("span.video");
                            iframe = $('<iframe/>', {
                                            'frameborder': 0,
                                            'class': 'tide',
                                            'width': '692',
                                            'height': '389',
                                            'src': 'http://player.vimeo.com/video/' + videoSpan.data("vimeoid") + '?autoplay=0&api=1'
                            });
                            videoSpan.replaceWith(iframe);

                                });
                    });
            });
            };
        });
});
 });
```